# Multiple field validation in Access VB?

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba

I'm looking for the best way to perform a multiple-field validation on an access form. It is as simple as the field being null or not but the conditions are tricky. The criteria is not working, meaning it always moves to the else while leaving the required field(s) blank. I am a beginner in access and definitely in VB coding but here is what I have so far via google searching:

```
Private Sub EventSummaryPreview_Click()
If _
    ( _
        Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And _
        Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_CEO Subform]![CEO_COMPANY_ID] & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Nz([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DT], 0 & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_CEO_USER_ID] & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Nz([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_AMT], 0 & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DEBIT_ACCT_NBR] & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Len(Me.NOTES & vbNullString) = 0 _
    ) Or _
    ( _
        Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And _
        Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DT] & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Nz([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_AMT], 0 & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_KEY] & vbNullString) = 0 And _
        Len(Me.NOTES & vbNullString) = 0 _
    ) _
Then
    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
    OK = True
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo_FPI_CASE_ENRICHMENT (DC_NO, ENRICH_FLG, ENRICH_FLG_TS, ENRICH_STATUS) " _
    & "VALUES (" & DC_NO & ", 1, Now(), 'OPEN')"
End If
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is hard to read. Why not use nested If statements?

Comment: Can you give me an example? I've been testing the code and it seems any more than 2 criteria in the IF statement doesn't get read into the condition.

Comment: i do not think you need vbnullstring. and also if you are checking for empty string or null. try isnothing(object.value) or object.value= ""

Comment: `If Me.Fraud_Typ = "Account Takeover" Then..
If IsNull(CEO_Company_ID) Then ..` But if the fields are required then you may want to make that so in your table. If they are only required under certain circumstances, then I guess you can just perform the validation via VBA.

Comment: Correct, the message box does not display when any of the elements past the first 2 variables are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I find it incredibly worthwhile to take the time to make something like this a tad more readable. You can do this by declaring multiple boolean variables and assigning them the values instead.

```
Dim cond1 as boolean, cond2 as boolean
Dim cond1A as boolean, cond1B as boolean, cond1C as boolean ' etc.,
Dim cond2A as boolean, cond2B as boolean, cond2C as boolean ' etc.,

' Breaking it down 1 by 1 helps you confirm that you have all of the proper criteria
' Putting these conditions in parenthesis will allow it to evaluate as true or false
cond1A = (Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover")
cond1B = ((Len([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_CEO Subform]![CEO_COMPANY_ID] & vbNullString) = 0)
cond1C = (Nz([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DT], 0 & vbNullString) = 0)
```

etc.,

```
cond1 = (cond1A AND cond1B AND cond1C)
cond2 = (cond2A AND cond2B AND cond2C)

If cond1 or cond2 then
    ' If either are true then do this Action
else
    ' neither are true Action
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not have been the best way to accomplish my goal but here is the code I ended up with. I'll change to Archias' suggestion when I have another release, thanks to all who provided input!

`If _
        IsNull(Me.FRAUD_TYP.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
            OK = True
    ElseIf (Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_KEY].Value)) Then
                If Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DT].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_CEO_USER_ID].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_CEO Subform]![CEO_COMPANY_ID].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_AMT].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DEBIT_ACCT_NBR].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull(Me.NOTES) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                End If
    ElseIf (Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And Not IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_KEY].Value)) Then
                If Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_CEO Subform]![CEO_COMPANY_ID].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_DT].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull([Form]![dbo_FPI_CASE_TRANS Subform]![TRANS_AMT].Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                ElseIf Me.FRAUD_TYP = "Account Takeover" And IsNull(Me.NOTES) Then
                    MsgBox "Required enrichment data elements are not populated, please correct your data."
                    OK = True
                End If
        Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo_FPI_CASE_ENRICHMENT (DC_NO, ENRICH_FLG, ENRICH_FLG_TS, ENRICH_STATUS) " _
        & "VALUES (" & DC_NO & ", 1, Now(), 'OPEN')"
    End If`